# SQL Query to Join inside a table

Tags: sql, performance

```
 ID | Doc ID | Acc Type | PID
 ============================
 1  |  3     |  WRAP    |234
 2  |  3     |  WRAP    |235
 3  |  4     |  NWRAP   |236
 4  |  5     |  WRAP-T  |237
 5  |  6     |  NWRAP-T |238
 6  |  3     |  WRAP    |241
 7  |  5     |  WRAP-T  |241
 8  |  4     |  NWRAP   |245
 9  |  6     |  NWRAP-T |245
```

From  the above table you can see some PID have only one document where as some (241 & 245) have multiple documents attached. I need to write a query to display PID and Acc Type for the Doc ID 3,4,5 or 6. But this query should not repeat multiple rows. In my case 241 should show as WRAP Acc Type and 245 should show as NWRAP Acc Type and both should not repeat.

Doc ID 3 & 5 are coupled same as 4 & 6. There can be process IDs which has Doc ID both 3 & 5 same as there can be DOC ID which has both 4 & 6. Also there can be PID which only has 3 or which only has 4 or which only has 5 or which only has 6. If 3 & 5 are attached with a PID we need to consider it as 3. If 4 & 6 are attached with a PID we need to consider it as 4.

Please help me in writing this query. Am totally tired of trying this as am new to SQL.

Comment: Can you please add the expected output for the given data...for better understanding of your requirement.

Comment: my expected out put is below,
234, WRAP
235, WRAP
236, NWRAP
237, WRAP-T
238, NWRAP-T
241, WRAP
245, NWRAP

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

i think this should work. I felt like it's much safer to explicitly order the results in the subquery, but you could probably do without it.

```
select * from (select doc_id, acc_type, PID from table order by PID,doc_id) t1 group by PID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try as below

## Explanation:

sub-query Q1 gives the min of doc_id for each pid, which is then joined to the table again to fetch only those rows based on the this pid and min_doc_id.

```
select Q1.pid,Q2.acc_type,Q1.min_doc_id from 
(select distinct pid ,min(doc_id) over (partition by pid) as min_doc_id  from n_bc1 ) Q1
join n_bc1 Q2
on Q1.pid = Q2.pid and q1.min_doc_id = q2.doc_id;
```

For your given data the output will be

```
pid acc_type    min_doc_id
234 WRAP        3
235 WRAP        3
236 NWRAP       4
237 WRAP-T      5
238 NWRAP-T     6
241 WRAP        3
245 NWRAP       4
```